# when i try to run the program, at the end its gives an error saying 'unexpected eof while parsing' how can i fix?

Tags: eoferror

```
def main():
    randOperation = Randomchoice(operation)

    while True:
        try:
            randOperation()
            randOperation = choice(operation)
            userAns=int(input("Answer: "))
            if userAns == answers:
                print("Correct!" + "\n")
                score = score + 1
                NumOfTries =NumOfTries + 1
            else:
                print("Incorrect!" + "\n")
                NumOfTries = NumOfTries + 1 #here is where the issue is
```

Comment: `try`, but no `catch`?

Comment: Please tag with the appropriate language tag.